# Create UPDATE function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I think that I already know the answer to this, but I thought that I would reach out to make sure that I was thinking about the question correctly.

> Create a user-defined function that updates the capacity of a classroom on a given new capacity.  Use an UPDATE clause to demonstrate the usage of your function.

Now, if I've read everything correctly, functions return values, either scalar or a result set table.  Functions wouldn't actually do any updating, would they?  Additionally, if you could create a function to do an update, why would you demonstrate it in an update clause?  Wouldn't you just use the UPDATE clause to begin with?

Like I said, I think I have the answer to this, but I thought it would be better to ask around.  Thanks.

Comment: Functions are dependent on their environment. Different databases use different programming languages. What environment are you in? But in general your function would look like update_capacity(10,50);   where "update_capacity" is the function, 10 is the id of the class and 50 is the new capacity.

Comment: What is this? A Quiz? Do you have any price for the one who wins?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question, didn't really think it through.  Working in Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: In SQL Server a user defined function cannot affect data, it can only accept parameters and return values. So there is some confusion about terminology. In SQL Server, this kind of thing is normally encapsulated in a `stored procedure`, rather than a function.

Comment: What Nick.McDermaid said is correct

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that should be an answer!

Comment: Now that the _actual_ question is posted, what I'm getting is that a UDF needs to be created to _work out the new capacity of classroom_, and that UDF needs to be used in an `UPDATE` statement to update that value. The question as previously worded did not make this clear

Comment: See, I agree with everything you said, but it seems odd to me that you would be given a new capacity to use in an UPDATE statement, in order to than use a UDF to work out that new capacity.  Frankly, I think that the question is worded oddly, but I think that I was finally able to work out what the answer should be.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it's an academic question or some kind of online quiz than it is unlikely to make any sense. It's making the mistake of appplying the functional programming world to the database world. This is bad habit to start with.